# How to fetch all products from one magento website and insert them into other

Tags: extensions

I want to fetch all products from one magento website to insert them into other magento installation. 
I've gone through google  and got confused on which methods I should use and which are all the methods I can skip. I need it to be done pragmatically

Can anyone streamline the ideas and give me a solution?

Comment: did you try with dataflow export and then import?

Comment: i dnt want to do manully. We need programtically

Comment: ok, please edit the question and put more details. you will receive more accurate responses

Answer (score 1):

There have no easy steps for update  products from under....

Here the details:

1.Create all attribute of  exiting website to new website.
2.Export product in csv format from

```
old site Admin>System>Import/Export>DataFlow Profile.
export>Export All Products
```

csv will  saved in old site `magento dir/var/export/`

3.Copy  folder and  `oldsitemagento/media/catalog/product (Except cache folder) to  newsitemagento/media/import`.

4.Now exported csv to  import to

```
new site>Admin>System>Import/Export>DataFlow Profile.
export>Export All Products.
```

5.Reindexing to new site